# How do I cancel my Github LFS subscription?

Tags: github

A long time ago I decided to try github lfs.  It didn't seem to help much, so I did what I thought would cancel it, but apparently it did not work.  I would like to know how to cancel a github lfs payment.  I've tried clicking the edit button and going to downgrade, but it bust downgrades to the $5/mo thing.  I've tried removing my payment info, but there is no option.

How do I make them stop charging me?  Also, I don't care what data they drop, I've got it all backed up.

Below is an image of the billing screen.  None of these links seemingly led anywhere.

[image: The github lfs page]

Answer (score 1):

Finally. Not sure if this is to late but for those experiencing a similar problem, to cancel subscription log in to GitHub, billing, Git LFS Data, edit: remove data packs and 0 from the dropdown menu, and downgrade  data plan.

Comment: In my case, this can be done after deleting the repository where I used the git LFS storage. After making sure the storage usage is 0, I can use the dropdown menu to choose from 1 to 0, then a downgrade can be done.

Answer (score 0):

What appears to have worked for me, and only because I'm using paypal, was to report the payment as a cancelled subscription, which then sets the authorization state of reoccurring payments to unauthorized.  Unfortunately, I didn't find an easy way to unauthorize the payment without also reporting them.

As a true answer to this question, it appears there is no way to simply cancel a LFS subscription.

Answer (score -1):

Before you can downgrade to a free subscription, make sure your account and repositories meets all the requirements of a free subscription. Especially:

- the number of collaborators
- public repositories with a custom domain
- etc.

More info and instructions [on the GitHub help pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/downgrading-your-github-subscription).

Comment: Nothing about LFS in your link

Comment: @SephReed could it be that the same reasoning applies to GitHub LFS?! My guess is that you do not meet all the free GitHub LFS requirements...

Comment: The idea of not meeting requirements to not pay for a service aside, the steps involved with meeting these requirements is not listed anywhere I can find.